Error during "apt-get full-upgrade": Missing libcrypt.so.1 library preventing libc6 configuration
When I try to do an apt-get full-upgrade, I get this error message:
Setting libc6:amd64 (2.36-9+deb12u7)...
/usr/bin/perl: error while loading shared libraries: libcrypt.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package libc6:amd64 (--configure):
installed libc6:amd64 ackage post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered during execution:
libc6:amd64
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

I'm trying to upgrade from Puppet 5 to Puppet 7. 
I can't do it through the Puppet repository.

You need to install libcrypt1:
sudo apt install libcrypt1

If apt doesn’t work, try
wget http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libx/libxcrypt/libcrypt1_4.4.33-2_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libcrypt1_4.4.33-2_amd64.deb

If wget doesn’t work, download the file on another computer, and copy it to the broken system.

Try the following steps to resolve your issue:

Edit /var/lib/dpkg/info/libc6:amd64.postinst using any text editor and search for set -e and comment this line.
Try to fix the broken packages using apt-get install --fix-broken note if you are not using root user then you need to add `sudo at the beginning of the command.
remove cached packages and force redownload it again by renaming info folder to any other names for example mv /var/lib/dpkg/info /var/lib/dpkg/info_old, then recreate info folder mkdir /var/lib/dpkg/info, finally repair the broken packages apt-get install --fix-broken


The first and third steps are really bad advice, the third step in particular will cause issues managing all the installed packages on the system.
